# Prove that $f'(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(0)=1$ and

$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x) \;\; \forall x , y \in \mathbb{R}$$

Prove that $f'(x)=1, \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt**

Since we have nothing to work with we are invoking the definition:

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\ 
 &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x-h)}{h}\\ 
 &\!\!\!\!\!\overset{x-h=u}{=\! =\! =\! =\!} \lim_{u \rightarrow x} \frac{f(u+h) - f(u)}{u-x} 
\end{align*}

My aim is somehow to make that $f'(0)=1$ appear and then a known limit. But so far no result. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The idea is to rewrite $f(x+h)-f(x)$ as $f(x)-f(x-h)$ as you have done, and then repeat this over and over to get $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x)-f(x-h)=f(x-h)-f(x-2h)=\dots.$$
When $x$ is an integer multiple of $h$, you can eventually reduce this to $f(h)-f(0)$, which you can then relate to $f'(0)$.

Comment: Nice catching up and continuing my idea.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, let $g(x):=f(x)-f(0)$.  With $y:=x$, in the original functional equation, we have $g(2x)=2\,g(x)$.  Substituting $\frac{x+y}2$ and $\frac{x-y}2$, respectively, for $x$ and $y$ in the original functional equation, we see that $g$ satisfies the Cauchy functional equation.  As $g$ is continuous at a point, being differentiable at $0$, it is given by $g(x)=kx$ for some constant $k$.  Thus, $f$ is a linear function.  The rest is evident.

Comment: (+1). Although I would really like to avoid the Cauchy functional as it is an early stage for this. It is taught a bit later.